# (Lenguaje C) Cómo obtener clave/valor (key,value)

Tags: c, codeblocks

¡Hola buenas!

Estaba realizando un diccionario en C, cuyo Header (Archivo .h) especifica que se deben implementar los siguientes métodos:

```
void dict_key(dict_node *pair, object *dst);
void dict_value(dict_node *pair, object *dst);
```

En el archivo .h encontramos:

```
typedef struct st_dict_node {
 object key; // llave
 object value; // valor
 struct st_dict_node *next;
} dict_node;

typedef struct {
 dict_node **first; //parejas
 int len; // tamanyo
} dict;
```

¿Alguien sabe cómo sería la implementación correcta de `dict_key` y `dict_value`? ¡Gracias!

Comment: Hola Angel, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Pulsa en [edit] para explicar qué has intentado y tus errores concretos. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es conseguir los datos `calve` y `valor` e igualar el valor que pasas por parámetro `dst` el código debería ser algo así:

Main:

```
dict_node * pair = NULL;
pair = (dict_node*)malloc(sizeof(dict_node));
int * dst;

pair->key = 2;
pair->value = 5;

dict_key( pair,  dst );
printf("Key : %i \n", *dst);
dict_value( pair,  dst );
printf("Value : %i \n", *dst);

return 0;
```

Llamadas:

```
void dict_key(dict_node *pair, int *dst)
{
    *dst = pair->key;
}
void dict_value(dict_node *pair, int *dst)
{
    *dst = pair->value;
}
```

Librería adicional:

```
#include <malloc.h>
```